How to use an external USB camera (UVC) in an Android project?
I’m a junior developer who recently started Android development.
I want to use an external USB camera (UVC camera) in my Android project but I’m not sure how to approach this.
From the Android documentation, it seems like the Camera2 API supports external cameras, but I couldn’t find any concrete examples or detailed steps to get started. I also explored using libraries like libusb and libuvc, but aside from adding implementation dependencies in the gradle file, I don’t know how to properly integrate these libraries into my project.
It seems like the most reliable way is to build these libraries myself and include the .so files in the project, but unfortunately, I don’t have enough time to dig deep into this process right now.
If anyone has experience working with external USB cameras on Android or has tackled a similar issue, I’d really appreciate your advice or pointers. Thanks in advance!

You need to request USB_PERMISSION dynamically when connecting the camera.
Add this to your AndroidManifest.xml:
xml
Copy code
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />


I’ve already requested all the necessary permissions.
However, my device is not being recognized by the Camera2 or CameraX API.
It seems that my USB camera is identified as a USB device, and when I check the UsbInterface class, it’s categorized as a camera device.
But I’m not sure how to use this in my app.
